Css variable value = another css variable doesn't update when overwritten
:root {
  --theme-color: #f00;
  --input-brdr: var(--theme-color);
}

.dark {
  --theme-color: #fff;
}

input {
  border: 2px solid var(--input-brdr);
}

The --input-brdr doesn't update to white when parent class is dark. Is there a workaround or anything? Seems it just keeps pulling the root value unless I add --input-brdr: var(--theme-color) again after the --theme-color: #fff;

You have to use border: 2px solid var(--theme-color);  because --input-brdr is only set in the :root, css doesn't apply any variable scoping.
